# Necessary condition for a graph to be Non-Hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory

Let us denote the edges incident on vertices of valence 2 as "required" as these edges has to be covered by a Hamiltonian circuit, if one exists on that (undirected) graph. Given a graph on which a proper subset of the "required" edges along with two edges incident on a vertex of valency $\geq 3$ form a cycle, can anything related to the Hamiltonicity of the graph be claimed? A few basic rules for the existence of Hamiltonian Cycles is listed here: http://www.mit.edu/~miforbes/ham_cycle.pdf  Can rule (4) be extended in any way to answer this query?

Comment: This confuses me.. if there is a cycle of "required edges" then surely this is a connected component of the graph which is therefore disconnected and not hamiltonian.

Comment: I share Gordon's confusion.  Also, it seems like the title should read: Is this a *sufficient* condition for a graph to be non-Hamiltonian, and the answer should be *yes*.  

Comment: Sorry.. the cycle is formed by all "required" edges except two. These two are the two edges incident to a vertex of valence $\geq 3$.

Comment: It looks that you mean necessary conditions for being Hamiltonian (or sufficient conditions for being non-Hamiltonian)

Comment: Simultaneously crossposted: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2777/necessary-condition-for-a-graph-to-be-non-hamiltonian

Comment: @ Tsuyoshi Ito: Is crossposting not allowed?

Comment: @Esha: I don't think cross-posting is disallowed, but it is certainly expected that you would **disclose** it, and if you think about it for a minute, you will realize why users expect this: it just strikes me as common courtesy.

Comment: cstheory.stackexchange link: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2777/necessary-condition-for-a-graph-to-be-non-hamiltonian